# Liferay Login error in liferay DXP after migration

Tags: liferay-7

After logging in with my custom login portlet into liferay portal,it again redirects to another login with an error in console

"Ignoring login attempt because the password parameter was found for the request with the referer header":
Everything is fine after second login
How to resolve this?

Comment: could you elaborate more your problem? Adding the code or attaching the stacktrace?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site
Plus: Have you googled for the log message?